# Inheritance and JSON Casting

Tags: c#, json, inheritance, casting, deserialization

I have a web service I am building, which uses a Base model of 
'BaseRequest'

```
public class BaseRequest
    {
        public string Operation { get; set; }
        public string SessionToken { get; set; }
        protected dynamic Content { get; set; }
        public bool IsEncrypted { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return RestClient.GetSerializerNative().Serialize(this);
        }

    }
```

I then cast this via the 'as NewClassType' to be my specialized types when it goes into the controller of each feature I am building out.
However, I can't seem to get the casting to work on one particular controller, I am unsure why not - because the same principle works elsewhere in the code.

The 'Content' field is a protected dynamic for two reasons.
The dynamic content could be 'anything' depending on the operation being carried out.
The protected is to prevent 'ambiguous name/field' Exceptions from the inheritance.

So my code:
The specialized type I am going to show here is

```
public class UploadImageRequest : BaseRequest
    {
        public new UIContent Content { get; set; }
    }
public class UIContent
{
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string ImageHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] BinaryData { get; set; }
}
```

The new keyword is to 'cover' or 'replace' the 'Content' from the base class with the definition of UIContent.
It should, from my other examples, change the dynamic, to the appropriate type.

So the actual implementation in the Execute method:

```
case "uploadimage":
                    BaseRequest uploadImage
                        = Default.GetJSSerializerNative().Deserialize<BaseRequest>(originalContent);

                    _responseToDeliver =
                        operations.uploadimage.Controller.Execute(uploadImage).ToString();

                    break;
```

Which then goes into :

```
public static Response Execute(BaseRequest request)
    {

        Response r = new Response();

        UploadImageRequest uir = request as UploadImageRequest;

        string name, hash = "";
        byte[] data = null;

        if (uir != null)
        {
            name = uir.Content.ImageName;
            hash = uir.Content.ImageHash;
            data = uir.Content.BinaryData;
        }
```

uir however, always ends up being null after the cast.

In another example I have:

```
case "getshowdata":
                    ShowDataRequest showRequest
                        = Default.GetJSSerializerNative().Deserialize<ShowDataRequest>(originalContent);

                    _responseToDeliver =
                        operations.TvShowInfo.Controller.Execute(showRequest).ToString();

                    break;
```

The ShowDataRequest looks like this:

```
public class ShowDataRequest : BaseRequest
    {
        public new ShowDataContentModel Content { get; set; }

    }

    public class ShowDataContentModel
    {
        public string ShowName { get; set; }
    }
```

And in its controller - it works perfectly.
So what is going on with my UploadImage operation here?
Why can it not be cast from the BaseRequest to the specialized type, while the ShowDataRequest can be.

Note : I've tried all sorts of things.
The case statement has the BaseRequest as the type I am Deserializing to for the Upload at the moment, but I have tried deserializing to intermediate types and all sorts.

Eg:

BaseRequest -> ImageRequest

ImageRequest is then the base class type for both
UploadImageRequest and AcquireImageRequest

Deserializing to ImageRequest - gets me the content info (I have it as a dynamic)
But when I then cast to Upload or Acquire - the whole class becomes null.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what was going wrong in my code.
In my examples where it worked : eg - the GetShowData requests.

It was being deserialized to the specialized type to start with.
Which meant that it was given all the data it ever needed for the life time of the request.

The Controllers execute method then accepts a BaseRequest type as argument, but the GetShowData request inherited this class, allowing it to be fed in, as it was basically a type of 'BaseRequest' but with extra data.
Once it is inside the Execute Method, the request object is still really a 'GetShowData' request, even though it enters as a BaseRequest.

Casting - which does not actually modify objects in memory, but just changes how the compiler or the runtime interprets objects, can then allow the runtime to interpret the request as the GetShowData request.
The reason it can do this, is because the request always was a GetShowData request to begin with, it was just being seen as a BaseRequest for the start of the Execute Method.

I think where I was going wrong in the UploadImage request, was that I had my inheritance backwards.
I was trying to deserialize to BaseRequest, feed it in as a BaseRequest, and then Cast it 'forwards' to the specialized type.
This doesn't work, because the class was initially created as BaseRequest, it didn't have knowledge of the specialized fields at this stage.

What I can do however, is Deserialize to the specialized type, feed it in as that type, in the Execute method - it can then accept BaseRequest, and then it can then cast back to the specialized type.

I remember a few years ago I thought this was analogous to an onion skin.
You can take layers of the onion (Specialized class), and even put them back on.
(Casting backwards - removes layers, casting back to original state-  puts them back on)

But you cannot put on layers that were never part of the onion. 
Eg: Casting the object to a class that it never was.

An example of this would be

BaseRequest
Inherited by NewRequest1
Inherited by NewRequest2

If you instantiate an object of NewRequest - you can cast to BaseRequest and then back to NewRequest1, but you cannot cast it to NewRequest2 - because it never was that type.

If you instantiate BaseRequest, you cannot cast to anything, because it was only ever created with BaseRequest's members/information.
Attempting to cast BaseRequest in this scenario, would be akin to trying to sellotape layers of skin from another onion, onto another onion - which just doesn't work - they wouldn't fit.

If someone does find a way to perform casting using the Dynamic field 'content' as a means to violate the inheritance requirement - I would be interested to hear.
Eg: if the dynamic Content field - contains a structure that is analogous to a specialized class, allow the casting or deserializing.